# Projeto que importa outros projetos do Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Tenho um projeto onde está toda a parte de configuração do Hibernate. No projeto final vou ter mais alguns projetos (Cadastro Pessoa por exemplo) que vai precisar o projeto que tem o Hibernate.

Como faço para configurar corretamente a importação do projeto do Hibernate nos outros projetos?

A principio a configuração que eu fiz funcionou, quando estou programando no projeto Cadastro de Pessoa eu consigo ter acesso as classes e métodos do projeto do Hibernate bem como acesso as classes e métodos das lib que estão lá configuradas.

O problema que quando eu rodo a aplicação ta dando classNotFound.

Comment: Você foi em propriedades do projeto na parte Bibliotecas -> Compilar e adicionou o projeto onde está a configuração do Hibernate?

Comment: Sim! Acho que o jeito vai ser seguir a dica do @nilson-uehara mesmo!

Comment: Você verá que o Maven ajuda demais. Boa sorte! (Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você precisa criar um JAR do projeto Hibernate para usá-lo como dependência no projeto cadastro.
Fica mais fácil usando o Maven.

Dê uma olhada neste vídeo, feito pelo Éder Magalhães da Yaw:

[Maven multi módulos](http://www.yaw.com.br/screencast/show/maven-multi-module/)